# Repeater with Linq - One Item with many child items

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, repeater, asprepeater

This is a challenging one.

I have 2 tables in the DB:

Class:
Id, Class Name etc.

Student:
ID, ClassID, Name etc.

I would like to have a Repeater which contains the following:

Class 1 Name

- Student 1
- Student 2

Class 2 Name

- Student 1
- Student 2

Now here's my Dilemma.

If I do a Select and Join with Linq something along these lines I get a new repeater Item for every student:

```
var query = (From c in Class
join s in Student on c.ID equals S.ClassID
select new {C,A}).Tolist();
```

However what I want is an Item for every CLASS with children items in each class as student.

Not too sure If I explained myself here... Ask questions and I'll answer.

Thank you very very much.

Comment: If I had to use Groupby I would still have to create the students on the fly right? Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested repeater and have the child repeater use the students of the parent class.

```
<asp:Repater ....>
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Students") %>'>
 </>
```

It depends a bit on your datamodel, but if you have the proper FK structure you do not need to manually join to the new {}. You coud simply force eager loading on the datacontext and do a Foreach over your class

Code example found here:
http://www.antiyes.com/nested-repeater

Comment: apart from that your design seems to accomodate only one class per student, that might not be sufficient

Comment: FK is structure is good. Nested Repeaters would work and I have to bind them on every iteration. That will probably work. I'll try it and I'll let you know. Thank you. 

I used Class and Student as an example to make it simpler to explain. It fits the model I am using. Thank you for point it out though

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work (essentially group the students before joining):

```
Student.GroupBy(s => s.ClassID)
       .Join(Class,
             g => g.Key,
             c => c.ID,
             (g, c) => new { Class = c, Students = g.ToArray() })
       .ToList();
```

The result is a list of anonymous type with `Class` = *a given class* and `Students` = *array of Students attending that class*.

Comment: If I had to use Groupby I would still have to create the students on the fly right? Or Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by 'creating students on the fly'. The answer was based on the assumption that class and student data is already available; I fail to understand your question if it's not.

Comment: Yes Data is already available. What I meant is. With a group by you'll get the classes and their students. But how will I get the UI structure I explained above. I can only think of achieving it using a nested Repeater.

Comment: @user1203996 nested Repeater is the best option UI-side. However, your question was a bit unclear, so I thought you asked for a correct way to gather your data, not how to display it. Do note that without any grouping, you're getting an awful lot of redundancy (multiple instances will hold the same `Class`).